# Insert new column based on column in other dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe, dataframe `A`:

```
---------------
A1    A2    A3   
1     aa    101        
2     bb    130
3     aa    160
4     cc    190
5     aa    200
---------------
```

dataframe `B`:

```
---------------
B1    B2    B3   
1     aa    111        
2     aa    171
3     bb    131
4     aa    131
5     cc    300
---------------
```

I want to create a new column in the `B` based on `A`

example: for first row in table `B`, it will check in table `A` if there is exist a row that `A2` equal `B2` and `A3` value is +- 30 from `B3`, if there is, then it will fill it with `A1` value as `B4` and the end result of this is

```
---------------------
B1    B2    B3    B4
1     aa    111   1
2     aa    171   3   (3 or 5, but it will chose first value, so it is 3)
3     bb    131   2
4     aa    131   1   (1 or 3, but it will chose first value, so it is 1)
5     cc    300   NaN (no conditions fulfilled)
---------------------
```

Is there any way to do this in `pandas`? or it is any suggestion to achieve that result?

Comment: Thank you, changed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join, filter by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html),[`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with  [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for first dupes and last use `map`:

*Notice - Requirement is default `RangeIndex` in both DataFrames.*

```
df = df2.reset_index().merge(df1.reset_index(), left_on='B2', right_on='A2', how='outer')
df = df[df['B3'].between(df['A3'] - 30, df['A3'] + 30)]

df = df.sort_values('index_y').drop_duplicates('index_x')
print (df)
   index_x  B1  B2   B3  index_y  A1  A2   A3
0        0   1  aa  111        0   1  aa  101
6        3   4  aa  131        0   1  aa  101
9        2   3  bb  131        1   2  bb  130
4        1   2  aa  171        2   3  aa  160


df2['B4'] = df2.index.to_series().map(df.set_index('index_x')['A1'])
print (df2)
   B1  B2   B3   B4
0   1  aa  111  1.0
1   2  aa  171  3.0
2   3  bb  131  2.0
3   4  aa  131  1.0
4   5  cc  300  NaN
```

Solution if values `A1` and `B1` are unique:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, left_on='B2', right_on='A2', how='outer')
df = df[df['B3'].between(df['A3'] - 30, df['A3'] + 30)]
df = df.sort_values('A1').drop_duplicates('B1')
df2['B4'] = df2['B1'].map(df.set_index('B1')['A1'])
print (df2)
   B1  B2   B3   B4
0   1  aa  111  1.0
1   2  aa  171  3.0
2   3  bb  131  2.0
3   4  aa  131  1.0
4   5  cc  300  NaN
```